# What is wrong with the code to create a database sqlit-net Xamarin form

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

[problem with data code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVTQH.png)

I build a student info app using Sqlite-net on Xamarin form if you can help me to follow the problem
I need to add info and display that info
but there is a problem in Fname

```
ObservableCollection<Student> data0 = new ObservableCollection<Student>(
           Student.Where(s => s.Fname.StartsWith(searchName)).ToList());
```

this is my cod

```
namespace Aj.Service
{
    public  class Database
    {
        private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection data;
        public  Database(string dbath)
        {
            data = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbath);
            data.CreateTableAsync<Student>().Wait();
        }
        public async Task<List<Student>> GetStudents()
        {
            var student = await data.Table<Student>().ToListAsync();
            if (student.Any())
            {
                await data.InsertAllAsync(objects: new Student[]
                {
                     new Student{ID=1,Fname="حسان",Mname="صالح",Evaluation=5,Lname="خالد", },
                     new Student{ID=2,Fname="فلاح",Mname="سعيد",Evaluation=5,Lname="معيض", },
                    new Student{ID=3,Fname="ثابت",Mname="شافي",Evaluation=5,Lname="عايض", },
                   new Student{ID=4,Fname="مطر",Mname="مصلح",Evaluation=5,Lname="رغدان", }
                });
               
            }
            return await data.Table<Student>().ToListAsync();
        }
        
      
        public  ObservableCollection<Student> GetStudentsByName(string searchName)
        {
           ObservableCollection<Student> data0 = new ObservableCollection<Student>(
               Student.Where(s => s.Fname.StartsWith(searchName)).ToList());
           return data0;
        }
    
       

      
    }
}
```

Comment: could you include your definition for `Student`? also: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using a class name `Student` in the query

```
public  ObservableCollection<Student> GetStudentsByName(string searchName)
    {
       var students = GetStudents();

       ObservableCollection<Student> data0 = new ObservableCollection<Student>(
           students.Where(s => s.Fname.StartsWith(searchName)).ToList());
       return data0;
    }
```